# Create Artifact in Archiva through Jenkins Pipeline / Gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline, archiva

I'm looking to create and upload an artifact to Archiva through a Jenkins pipeline node.  I've found plenty of documentation for doing this in [Artifactory](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+-+Working+With+the+Pipeline+Jenkins+Plugin), but I am having trouble getting footing on how to handle this with Archiva.

For reference, the Artifactory equivalent of what I'm trying to do is something on the order of:

```
node {
    def server = Artifactory.server 'my-server-id'

    stage('Build') {
        // ...
    }

    stage('Test') {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    stage('Archive') {
        def uploadSpec = """{
            "files": [
                {
                    "pattern": "build/files",
                    "target": "repo/path/"
                }
            ]
        }"""
        server.upload(uploadSpec)
    }
}
```

But now I want to handle this in Archiva instead (or with a generic Maven repository in general).  For what it's worth, I'm using a Gradle build system, if getting Jenkins to tell Gradle to upload to Archiva would be an easier prospect.

Comment: did you find any solution?